# Python scraping pages after hitting the "load more results" button

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, web-scraping, python-requests

How do you scrape a web page with infinite scrolling?

My first try was using Selenium, but it detects as robot:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.bloomberg.com/search?query=indonesia%20mining'
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(url)
html = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')
page_num = 0

while driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.contentWell__a8d28605a5'):
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.contentWell__a8d28605a5').click()
    page_num += 1
    print("getting page number "+str(page_num))
    time.sleep(1)

html = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
titles = soup.find_all('div', {"class":"text__d88756958e withThumbnail__c4ffc902a6"})

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['judul', 'link'])
news = {}
for t in titles:
    news['judul'] = t.find('a', {'class':'headline__96ba1917df'}).text.strip()
    news['link'] = t.find('a', {'class':'headline__96ba1917df'}).get('href')
    df = df.append(news, ignore_index=True)
```

any idea how to limit the maximum page number?

Comment: "My first try was using Selenium, but it detects as robot" Well then, isn't that the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel because the webstite detects as robot so the output dataframe is none, so I guess if the page number is limit to 10 for example, the website won't detect it as robot. cmiiw

Comment: Okay, so did you try to look up ways to prevent the website from detecting a robot? Actually, scrap that. First, did you check whether the website is okay with you scraping it? Did you check if it offers a proper API to get the information you want?